# Build Fail when connecting a branch identical to master in amplify studio

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, amplifyjs

My master branch in amplify studio is set up well and works with amplify studio. I created a new branch from master in GitHub and then I connected to that branch in amplify studio. However, the build fails in front end with error "Framework web not supported".
I was getting this error initially when trying to connect to master in amplify studio. I had not selected the monorepo option and selected the folder that had the app.
So I think this is why I'm getting the "Framework web not supported" error when connecting a different branch in amplify studio as there is no option to select the folder that has the app. I am not sure how to work around this. Would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.